# Verifying A JWT With The Crypto Web API

Tags: javascript, jwt, cryptography, subtlecrypto

I am trying to verify a JSON Web Token using the Web Crypto API. This is my code so far:

```js
async function verify(user: string) {
  const secret = await crypto.subtle.importKey(
    "raw",
    new TextEncoder().encode(process.env.SECRET!),
    {
      name: "HMAC",
      hash: { name: "SHA-256" },
    },
    false,
    ["verify"]
  );

  return crypto.subtle.verify(
    "HMAC",
    secret,
    Buffer.from(user.split(".")[2], "base64url"),
    new TextEncoder().encode(user.split(".").splice(0, 2).join())
  );
}
```

The parameter `user` contains the JWT. The variable `process.env.SECRET` contains the secret/key that was used to sign the token. It is of type string.

However, this function seems to always return false, even when passed a valid token. Can somebody help me figure out what I am doing wrong? Also, I would prefer not to use any external libraries for this.

Comment: Note that for [`join()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join?retiredLocale=en#parameters) the separator defaults to `,` (i.e. `.` must be explicitly specified). If the problem persists post non-productive test data for JWT and secret.

Comment: Thanks, I completely forgot that! This solved my issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am just repeating what @Topaco commented on the original question, because that solved my issue and this way I can accept an answer and thereby close this.

What I forgot what the argument for the `join()` method. For anybody else who wants to use the code I'll post the working version below.

```js
async function verify(user: string) {
  const secret = await crypto.subtle.importKey(
    "raw",
    new TextEncoder().encode(process.env.SECRET!),
    {
      name: "HMAC",
      hash: { name: "SHA-256" },
    },
    false,
    ["verify"]
  );

  return crypto.subtle.verify(
    "HMAC",
    secret,
    Buffer.from(user.split(".")[2], "base64url"),
    new TextEncoder().encode(user.split(".").splice(0, 2).join("."))
  );
}
```